# Is there a way to update a window's theme automatically?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This is my current events loop, and I was wondering if there is a way to take the new theme and automatically apply it to the window upon the calling of the event?

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(values)
    try:
        if values[0] == "event1":
            sg.theme(new_theme = theme1)

        elif values[0] == "event2":
            sg.theme(new_theme = theme2)
            
    except:
        pass
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
        break
```

Currently all I am able to update is the theme "in the background", as running the .theme() without parameters returns that the theme has been updated correctly

I have tried using multiple methods of refreshing the window, but as I am new to this module I am most likely missing some key details, as the window appears unchanged

Comment: Maybe you can refer https://github.com/definite-d/psg_reskinner/